# Google Big Query Option 20056 is not supported by this curl implementation

Tags: php, curl, google-bigquery

I am trying to run Big query in php in google app engine and getting following error

Uncaught exception 'Google\Cloud\Core\Exception\ServiceException' with message 'Option 20056 is not supported by this curl implementation

google_app_engine.enable_curl_lite = “1” in php.ini

```
function run_query($projectId, $query)
{
$bigQuery = new BigQueryClient([
    'projectId' => $projectId,
]);
echo"inside run_query function";
echo "<br>".$query."<br>";
/*$query = 'SELECT TOP(corpus, 10) as title, COUNT(*) as unique_words ' .
         'FROM [publicdata:samples.shakespeare]';
$options = ['useLegacySql' => true];
*/

$query='SELECT COUNT(A.id) as unique FROM [aaa.bbb.ccc] A '.
        'LEFT JOIN [aaa.bbb.ccc] B '.
        'on (A.id=B.primeid) WHERE B.result is null OR B.result <=25 ';

echo "<br>".$query."<br>";
$useLegacySql=true;
$options = ['useLegacySql' => $useLegacySql];
$queryResults = $bigQuery->runQuery($query, $options);

if ($queryResults->isComplete()) {
    echo "query complete";
    $i = 0;
    $rows = $queryResults->rows();
    foreach ($rows as $row) {
        printf('--- Row %s ---' . PHP_EOL, ++$i);
        foreach ($row as $column => $value) {
            printf('%s: %s' . PHP_EOL, $column, $value);
        }
    }
    printf('Found %s row(s)' . PHP_EOL, $i);
} else {
    echo "query not complete";
    throw new Exception('The query failed to complete');
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the php ini setting google_app_engine.enable_curl_lite to "0" in php.ini.

cURL lite doesn't have the same feature set as the full version of cURL

Comment: I tried that but did not work BUt i got it working by adding                
     extension = "php_curl.dll" in php.ini file. Thanks delboy1978uk

Answer (score 0):

I got it working by adding `extension = "php_curl.dll"` in php.ini file.